# Unity: resources.bundle isn't added to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, unity-game-engine, bundle

I used to copy/paste my IOS plugin files inside Plugins/IOS folder on my Unity project, but it doesn't work for bundles (as it has directory structure). 
I can't beleave there is no way to generate xcode project from unity with .bundle inside?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity3D will not contains folders in the Plugins/iOS to Xcode project. In fact Unity3D will only auto merge source file and .a library for you, as described by [Unity3D's doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html):

> Automated plugin integration Unity iOS supports automated plugin
>   integration in a limited way. All files with extensions
>   .a,.m,.mm,.c,.cpp located in the Assets/Plugins/iOS folder will be
>   merged into the generated Xcode project automatically. However,
>   merging is done by symlinking files from Assets/Plugins/iOS to the
>   final destination, which might affect some workflows. The .h files are
>   not included in the Xcode project tree, but they appear on the
>   destination file system, thus allowing compilation of .m/.mm/.c/.cpp
>   files.
>
> Note: subfolders are currently not supported.

But you can use the [PostprocessBuildPlayer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PostProcessAttribute.html) attribute to implement this yourself. I made a tool for this purpose called `XUPorter`, which can make exporting and libraries setting easier from Unity3D to Xcode. You may want to see it [on GitHub](https://github.com/onevcat/XUPorter). There is a demo in the package and you may set your bundle under the 'folders' tag.

Comment: btw, I've already included PostprocessBuildPlayer to include some of frameworks (e.g AdSupport.framework) which aren't added by default. Thanks, have to look on this.

Comment: @onevcat sounds good your XUPorter :) Will try it out occasionally

Comment: @Kay Welcome to fork and send pull request :)

Comment: I'm using XUPorter and it's great, but for some reason, xibs aren't copied from inside the Resources folder to the xCode, know why?